# Remove rvalueness, keep lvalue references (standard type trait available?)

Tags: c++, c++14, rvalue-reference, type-traits, perfect-forwarding

I'm trying to write a function that returns a subset of a variadic argument pack under the form of an `std::tuple`. The function should ideally have no runtime overhead (no unnecessary copies), and it should allow users to access `lvalue` references and modify them.

Value types, `lvalue` references and `const lvalue` references should be maintained. Temporaries (`rvalue` references), should be "converted" to value types to avoid creating invalid references (references to temporaries).

Example of desired results:

```
int lr = 5;
const int& clr = lr;

auto t = make_subpack_tuple(lr, clr, 5);

static_assert(is_same
<
    decltype(t), 
    std::tuple<int&, const int&, int>
>{}, "");

// Ok, modifies lr:
std::get<0>(t) = 10;

// Compile-time error, intended:
// std::get<1>(t) = 20;

// Ok, 5 was moved into the tuple:
std::get<2>(t) = 30;
```

Example incomplete implementation:

```
template<typename... Ts>
auto make_subpack_tuple(Ts&&... xs)
{
    return std::tuple
    <
        some_type_trait<decltype(xs)>...
    >
    (
        std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...
    );
}
```

Does what I am trying to do make sense?

Is there a standard type-trait that can be used in place of `some_type_trait`? Or should I implement my own solution?

Comment: I'm just curious. Why are you interested in doing this? What problem are you solving?

Comment: I'm implementing something similar to a `static_for` that executes a callable object over heterogeneous values with an user-specified arity, and also allows the user to retrieve the current iteration number at compile time and break/continue *(exit early)* at compile time using `static_if`. Part of the implementation requires passing the first `N` arguments of the variadic argument pack to another inner function, and I was trying to generalize that by defining some variadic argument pack manipulation functions. Other than `nth<I>`, I require `subpack<I, J>` to fully generalize that behavior

Comment: By user-specified arity, I mean that the `static_for` iterates over the heterogeneous values in groups of `N` (where `N` is a template parameter specified by the user). The callable object that represents the body of the `static_for` needs to have an `operator()` with the same arity. Also, I'm doing all of this for an open-source C++14 general purpose library ([vrm_core](https://github.com/SuperV1234/vrm_core)), written for fun and learning purposes. Hope that answers your question :)

Comment: Do not use `decltype(xs)`. The type pack `Ts...` is exactly what you need. So try `std::tuple<Ts...>`

Comment: @AndreyNasonov: works perfectly, not sure how I didn't think about that. Thanks! Could you post this solution again as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution for you will be

```
template<typename... Ts>
auto make_subpack_tuple(Ts&&... xs)
{
    return std::tuple<Ts...>(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
}
```

According to [template argument deduction rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), the parameter pack `Ts...` will contain only cv-qualified types and lvalues. The information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward) may be useful too.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just like to chime in that I ran into this same not-really-a-problem ("I think I need to decay rvalue references and keep lvalue references untouched") while implementing an efficient version of [Nick Athanasios's foldable `Op<operation>`](https://ngathanasiou.wordpress.com/2015/12/15/182/). I had had this mess:

```
template<class Pack, class Op>
struct Foldable
{
    mystery_trait_t<Pack> value;
    const Op& op;

    template<class RhsPack>
    auto operator*(const Foldable<RhsPack, Op>& rhs) const {
        return op(static_cast<std::decay_t<Pack>>(
            (op.f)(std::move(value), std::move(rhs.value))
        ));
    }

    operator mystery_trait_t<Pack> () && {
        return std::move(value);
    }
};

template<class Pack>
auto NamedOperator::operator()(Pack&& value) const {
    return Foldable<Pack, NamedOperator>(std::forward<Pack>(value), *this);
}
```

and (after puzzling for a bit, and then starting to ask a SO question, and finding this existing question/answer, and adding a `static_assert` to my implementation of `mystery_trait_t` to verify that it was never actually invoked with an rvalue reference type!) it turned out that all I actually needed was

```
template<class Pack, class Op>
struct Foldable
{
    Pack value;
    const Op& op;

    template<class RhsPack>
    auto operator*(const Foldable<RhsPack, Op>& rhs) const {
        return op(
            (op.f)(std::move(value), std::move(rhs.value))
        );
    }

    operator Pack () && {
        return std::move(value);
    }
};
```

[(See my whole code on Wandbox.)](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IdU2rQfQja5jjQp4)

This "answer" of mine doesn't contribute any new information, but I thought it would be useful to share, because it just goes to show that even if you think you're *way deep* in template metaprogramming and are *sure* you need this "conditional decay" behavior... you really don't need it!

There might be a corollary general rule that **writing `any_template<T&&>` is always a code smell.** In Vittorio's original question, he effectively did that twice, although both times it was hidden by `decltype` syntax:

```
some_type_trait<decltype(xs)>...  // should have been `Ts...`
std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)... // could equally well be `std::forward<Ts>(xs)...`
```